# What should be the status code for protocol mismatch error HTTP/HTTPS?

Tags: api, http-status-codes

I am referring to the W3 specification for the finding the correct HTTP API status code, to handle a request when a protocol mismatch occurs and according to the specifications, 403 Forbidden status comes closest in understanding as it says

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the **request SHOULD NOT be repeated**.

Here's the specification link: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4

Please share if any W3 official documentation states the same or any other major Platform implements it that way.